# send email by smtp and ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I am beginner in `ASP.NET MVC` and trying to get email using `smtp server` and `ajax` in webApplication. When user click on the button my code will generate the email which will be send to desired **ID**. I am successfully getting my all values by debug the code. But, I am not able to receive the email there. Although, I am also getting **Success** massage from browser. But no email is there, in my desirable account.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" onclick="SendEmail()" >Click to send Email</a>
</div>

<script>
    var SendEmail = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Feedbacks/SendMailToUser",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

**FeedbacksController.cs**

```
public JsonResult SendMailToUser() {
            bool result = false;
            result = SendEmail("abc@gmail.com", "Test", "<p>Hi abc,<br/>This message is for testing purpose. So don't be upset.<br/>Kind Regards,<br/>abc</p>");
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody) {
            try
            {
                string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
                string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 578);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Timeout = 100000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

                client.Send(mailMessage);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SenderEmail" value="abc@gmail.com" />
    <add key="SenderPassword" value="********" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: What is the value of `data` in your ajax callback ? Is it true or false ? If it is false you know which part of your code is being executed.

Comment: Change your port number as well as change enableSSL to false

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers only if you want to send insecure email :-)

Comment: @ADyson - I think this is the main reason why mail is not working successfully.!

Comment: If the ajax returns false, then an exception must be occurring. But you are throwing that exception away in your catch block. You should log it, or at least step through the code in debug mode and examine the exception. That will give you a clue as to the underlying nature of the problem. It's also worth noting that sending an email does not guarantee receiving an email. The most your application can do is verify that the mail was sent to the server successfully. It can't guarantee delivery of the email to the recipient. Testing by testing for delivery is not a complete test.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers it could be one reason, although you can't say that for certain without seeing an error message to that effect. But if OP wants a secure connection to the mail server, which is perfectly achievable, then the solution is not to throw away security just to get a "working" bit of code. Instead we should find the fault and fix it. If that's your normal approach to security then I would not trust you with my data.

Comment: I think you're set the wrong port number for SMTP service, it should be like this: `SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);` (GMail's SMTP TLS port is 587 instead of 578, or use 465 for SSL). Try changing the port number as suggested and see if it sending the generated mail.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank you so much. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SmtpClient` without object initializer:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem because I was using wrong port number. When I use

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
```

instead of

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 578);
```

I got email there.

Answer (score 0):

you insert wrong port you can use simple 587 and also 25